# How to connect one Xbox 360 Wireless controller to PC and Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox360

I'm trying to have my PC and Xbox 360 working with one and the same Xbox 360 Wireless Controller. (PC has a proper adapter, of course)
The problem is, the controller can be synced with only one device at a time. Also, the pair/unpair process is kind of wonky and sometimes it takes few tries to work.

Is there anything to make it easier or even pair the controller with 2 devices? (it'd connect to the one turned on)

Comment: No;  Xbox 360 uses it's own communication standard.

Comment: Speculating heavily here, I would guess that there is some amount of encryption in the communications, and so this would be technically possible only if you could make the PC identify itself as the Xbox 360, which would essentially require acquiring a "security key" (essentially a password) from the Xbox 360.  This is probably not a process that Microsoft publicly documents, and so the feasibility of doing this is probably not easy (as it will require notable research to pull this off).

Comment: @Ramhound I'm like 90% sure the play and charge cable only does charging, communication is still put through the wireless radio.

Comment: @MichaelFrank - I never said to use the plug and charge cable.

Comment: @Ramhound That's the only type of cable that will fit with the X360 controller though, so by the powers of deduction...!

Comment: @MichaelFrank - Must be confusing myself with the original Xbox One controller which had a USB port.

Comment: @Ramhound Possibly, I only know this since I looked into it for a while as I had a controller with a broken battery caddy and wanted to convert to wired.

Comment: @TOOGAM That's an interesting idea. I'll dig around, thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot connect it to both at the same time.

The controller was not designed this way and cannot handle remember multiples hosts.

Comment: Can you expand on this?  e.g., why?  under any condition? explanation or citation?  This could well be correct, but how does anyone know it isn't simply opinion, or that you just aren't familiar with a solution, with only this to go on?  [from review](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/722369)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/722369)

Comment: @Burgi - It actually does.

Comment: @Zulgrib That seems to be true since Google wouldn't help me out and so I've ended here. It doesn't seem to be explicitly said anywhere, though. I hoped for some kind of a hack or an undocumented feature which would allow to do so.

Comment: @fixer1234 It is technically not possible, period.